# What is proper way to use react hooks when calling javascript functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just learning how hooks work in larger applications. I'm trying to figure out what the correct pattern is here. I typically wrap my api calls in their own files. For instance, I might call out to get a list of customers in a file Customers.Api.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const client = await getApiClient();
const reply = await client.get(`${baseUrl}/customers`);
return reply;
```

The job of getApiClient() is to get an axios instance that already has the Authorization header added. I am getting this from Auth0, but that part doesn't matter as I am really looking for the pattern here and not specifics to Auth0, could be any hook:

```
// Engine.Api.js
// Inside an axios interceptor called from getApiClient()
const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0(); // <-- this is not allowed in a plain js func

const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({}); 
request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
...
return request
```

Since my token comes from a hook, how should I be setting this up?

I don't want to do this every time:

```
const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({});
const client = await getApiClient();
const reply = await client.get(`${baseUrl}/customers`,{
  headers: `Authorization: Bearer ${token}`,
})
```

I would prefer some way to do this (or something similar):

```
const customers = await getCustomers();
```

getCustomers() would live in Customers.Api.js and would have something like:

```
const client = await getApiClient(); // <-- this would use interceptor to add bearer
return await client.get(`${baseUrl}/customers`);
```

> Final Solution

After looking at what Andrey had to say, I finally got to where I needed to be. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
const axiosClient = axios.create();

export function useApiClient() {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently, isLoading } = useAuth0();
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    loading: true,
    authHeader: null,
    token: '',
    client: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (!isLoading) {
        if (state.token === '') {
          const apiToken = await getAccessTokenSilently({
            audience: 'https://example.com/',
            scope: 'read:current_user',
          });
          setState({ ...state, authHeader: { Authorization: `Bearer ${apiToken}` }, token: apiToken });
    }

    if (state.token && !state.client && state.loading) {
      setState({ loading: false, client: axiosClient });
    }
  }
})();
}, [getAccessTokenSilently, state, isLoading]);
  return { ...state };
```

}

I also modified it a lot after that as this was not really my true use case, but it identified what I was not understanding.
Thanks Andrey!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually solved by creating another hook that would wrap all necessary logic inside.

Auth0 documentation actually has an example of that: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#4-create-a-useapi-hook-for-accessing-protected-apis-with-an-access-token

In your case you can do smth like this:

**Customers.Api.js**:

```js
export function useCustomers() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ customers: [] });
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({});
      const client = await getApiClient();
      const reply = await client.get(`${baseUrl}/customers`,{
        headers: `Authorization: Bearer ${token}`,
      })
      setState({ customers: reply.data });
    })
  });
  return state;
}
```

(not tested, might not actually work, but hopefully the idea is clear)

**in a component**:

```js
const { customers } = useCustomers();
```

Next step would be to generalize `useCustomers` hook into smth like `useApi` and inside `useCustomers` simply call `useApi`.

Also you might find official [Building Your Own Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) documentation helpful, it explains most common gotchas.